# How to get the CRC32 checksum out of a large file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code works for the sha256 hash, even if the files are large:

```
require "digest"

sha256 = Digest::SHA256.file "video.mkv"
puts "Checksum SHA256: #{sha256.hexdigest}"
```

But what I need is the CRC32 value and Zlib only works for string and small files.

```
require "zlib"

calc = IO.binread("video.mkv")
crc32 = Zlib.crc32(calc) 

# file too big for single read (IOError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the solution I found, but I think there's room for improvement.

```
require "zlib"

crc32 = ""
range = 104857600 #100MB

File.open("video.mkv") do |f|
    while byte = f.read(range)       
        begin
            crc32 = Zlib::crc32(byte, crc32)
        rescue
            crc32 = Zlib::crc32(byte)
        end         
    end
end

puts crc32.to_s(16)
```

For a 3GB file it took 2 minutes.